# Conky Alignment

Tags: window, conky

When I set conky alignment to 'middle_right', it starts acting an another window and when I maximise other windows, e.g. firefox, it stops and touches with conky boundary.

[image: conky panel]

Comment: The real issue may be not the value in the "alignment" field, but the value in "own_window_type". Is your current value equal to "panel"? You may use "normal" or "dock".

Comment: @LorenzKeel, please have a look into this https://ibb.co/DMrxWFg

Comment: Try to replace "panel" with "dock" or "normal".

Comment: Changing (own_window_type)value from 'panel' to 'normal' in (conky.conf) worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `own_window_type` variable description in [conky documentation](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html):

> if own_window is yes, you may specify type normal, desktop, dock,
> panel or override (default: normal). Desktop windows are special
> windows that have no window decorations; are always visible on your
> desktop; do not appear in your pager or taskbar; and are sticky across
> all workspaces. Panel windows reserve space along a desktop edge, just
> like panels and taskbars, preventing maximized windows from
> overlapping them. The edge is chosen based on the alignment option.
> Override windows are not under the control of the window manager.
> Hints are ignored. This type of window can be useful for certain
> situations.

The use of `panel` value for the variable `own_window_type` leads to the undesired behavior.
The value to use for your purpose is `normal`, so that your conky configuration must have the following lines:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing ***own_window_type*** value from ***panel*** to ***normal*** in ***conky.conf*** worked!